# how to insert in a date/time ms access field using java sql INSERT query

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I want to add some date and time in the MS Access, but my date and time variable is a string. i.e

```
String dt="12/2/2014 9:00 PM"; //this is selected from a calender component and a ComboBox
```

While MS Access field's type is (Date/Time). How to convert my string to date/time type so that it can be inserted to the field? Can you please illustrate with some line of code? As I am not an expert in java. Something like what I want:

step1: Converting String to date time field

step2: statement.executeUpdate(Insert into table (Date-Time) Values(??????)

Comment: Your question is not very clear/readable...

Answer (score 2):

**Step:1 Converting String to date time field:**

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
String stringDate = "12/2/2014 9:00 PM";
java.util.Date date = df.parse(stringDate);
```

This will give you the date from string.
For more details on SimpleDateFormat [See the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

**Step 2:**

```
String query = "Insert into table MyTable(dateColumn) Values(?)";
PreparedStatement ps  = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setTimestamp(1,new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Here are some more [details on using prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: i have used the above code. works fine but how to use condition with this??
i.e  "Insert into table MyTable(dateColumn) Values(?) where title='abc'";