# Insert String type variables and a date type variable in MS access using java and sql INSERT Query

Tags: java, sql

I posted a problem on how to convert string date to a date/time field to be added in access database: here is the Link

[how to insert in a date/time ms access field using java sql INSERT query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375586/how-to-insert-in-a-date-time-ms-access-field-using-java-sql-insert-query)

I found a solution which i used here, here is my code

```
        if(b==c.t.addR){
        String n=Integer.toString(4);
        String t=c.t.titlefield.getText();
        String d=c.t.datefield.getText();
        String p=c.t.progressfield.getText();
        String pr=c.t.pselection;
        String s="Open";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");

        try {
            date = df.parse(d);
            String query = "INSERT into Records (Deadline) Values(?)";
            PreparedStatement ps  = c.b.con.prepareStatement(query);

            ps.setTimestamp(1,new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
            ps.executeUpdate();

        }catch (Exception er) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            er.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            c.b.st.executeUpdate("INSERT into Records (Title,Progress,Priority,Status) VALUES('"+t+"','"+p+"','"+pr+"','"+s+"') ");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Added");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

The problem now arise is that,, Date is added in a separate record while Other fields like title,progress etc are added in another!!! 
How to INSERT date and other string fields in a single record. 
Plz illustrate with some lines of code!!! Previous solution's modification will be very much helpful,, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> How to INSERT date and other string fields in a single record

make it a one insert statement rather than 2.

```
   String query = "INSERT into Records (Deadline,Title,Progress,Priority,Status) Values(?,?,?,?)"
 PreparedStatement ps  = c.b.con.prepareStatement(query);

                ps.setTimestamp(1,new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
                ps.setString(2,t);
                ps.setString(3,p);
                ps.setSring(4,pr);
                ps.setString(5,s);
                ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: But then How will i prepare the statement,,, plz illustrate!!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert int oa single record by executing one sql statement.  You will just need to add the columns to the statement and set their values with the prepared statement.  This is a more secure way of performing the insert instead of concatenating a String.

```
if(b==c.t.addR){
    String n=Integer.toString(4);
    String t=c.t.titlefield.getText();
    String d=c.t.datefield.getText();
    String p=c.t.progressfield.getText();
    String pr=c.t.pselection;
    String s="Open";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");

    try {
       date = df.parse(d);
       String query = "INSERT into Records (Deadline,Title,Progress,Priority,Status)" 
           + "Values(?, ?, ?, ?,?)";

       PreparedStatement ps  = c.b.con.prepareStatement(query);

       ps.setTimestamp(1,new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
       ps.setString(2,t);
       ps.setString(3,p);
       ps.setSring(4,pr);
       ps.setString(5,s);
       ps.executeUpdate();

        }catch (Exception er) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          er.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```