# Accessing Date/Time Data stored in MS-Access Database from JAVA

Tags: java, date, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using MS-Access Database for my application. now I want to store current date in DB from JAVA. Following Code Segment stores date data in Database but it stores the incorrect value: 6/6/1905. The datatype in MS-Access is Date/Time. I used following code segment for setting current date:

```
data.setModifyDate(new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
```

The type of modifyDate is java.sql.Date.
The insert query is as follows:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO testTable(id, tName, modifyDate ) " +
                        " VALUES ("+"'"+data.getId()+"'"+","
                                    +"'"+data.getTName()+"'"+","
                                    +data.getModifyDate()+")";

Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.execute(query);
```

TimeStamp is not supported in MS-Access 2007. So, how can I store the correct date value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375586/how-to-insert-in-a-date-time-ms-access-field-using-java-sql-insert-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Timestamp` if you use a *parameterized query* to do the INSERT (which you really should be doing in any case). The following code works for me:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + 
                    "Dbq=C:\\__tmp\\Database1.accdb;");

            PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO testTable (id, tName, modifyDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            s.setString(1, "foo");
            s.setString(2, "bar");
            s.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
            s.execute();
            s.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert the date/time as printed by the Date class of java. 
I think MSAccess needs its date/time as #YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS# so try to use SimpleDateFormat to have the right format in the insert query.

Hope this helps.